# Wpf multiple combobox binding to one property

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am having a data grid, one of its cells is a combo box like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Applications"  RowStyle="{StaticResource CollapsedRow}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}">

<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Button Content='&#709;' FontSize="9" Name="ExpanderButton" Click="OnGroupChange" />
      </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

 <DataGridTextColumn Width="181" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />

</DataGrid.Columns>

<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Cabins, 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
       SelectedValuePath="Id" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
       SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedCabin,
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
       mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{Binding Path=DataContext.CabinsWatermark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                                                      Height="2" Width="300" Margin="10 5 10 10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GuidConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ComboBox>
 </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

</DataGrid>
```

And as you see in each row there ia a combo box in detail row (expanded row using button), each combo box is binded to one property:

```
 private Guid? selectedCabin;
    public override  Guid? SelectedCabin
    {
        get => selectedCabin;
        set
        {
            selectedCabin = value;
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
```

Now problem is when i select item in combo box i am getting not single value but couple of them (I suppose there are all values from one combo box I made a selection on), to make sure i double checked with test code behind:

```
     private void ComboBox_OnSelectCabinChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var combo = (ComboBox)sender;

        if (combo != null && combo.IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            ((ApplicationsViewModel)DataContext).SelectedCabin = (Guid?)sender;
            combo.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

And I am getting here and combo box item list and casting exception. What could be the root cause of this and is there a way to bind multiple combo box values to one property, so is i select one it will override another.

Comment: It seems like you are binding the `SelectedValue` of *all* row details ComboBoxes to the same source property. And you can't cast the `sender` argument to a `Guid?`. Try to cast the `SelecteedValue` property of the `ComboBox`: `SelectedCabin = (Guid?)combo.SelectedValue;`.

Comment: I knew it was something trivial, well it worked :) now I am gonna try to do it without code behind, is its even possible.

Comment: You could use an interaction trigger. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are binding the `SelectedValue` of *all* row details `ComboBoxes` to the same source property. And you can't cast the `sender` argument to a `Guid?`. Try to cast the `SelecteedValue` property of the `ComboBox`:

```
SelectedCabin = (Guid?)combo.SelectedValue;
```

If you don't want to handle the `SelectionChanged` event in the view, you could use an interaction trigger that executes a command that sets the source property. Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) for more information about this.